# Moving an on premise SOA application off premise or into the cloud

Tags: java, cloud, external, soa

I've currently designed a Java web application which was intended to be installed within the customers environment. In terms of interconnectivity it consists of 5-10 REST APIs with a simple data transfer.

i.e. You give me x, i'll calculate and return y.

I'm wondering what areas would need to be rethought (or thought for the first time) if I intend to move this off premise. From a customers point of view they're still accessing the same functionality, just via a different URL.

As far as I can tell it's really more figuring out deployment and networking changes than application changes.

Not sure if i'm not thinking broadly enough.

I know absolutely nothing about the cloud but I imagine provisioning and setting up an image is the main issue there. But ultimately the application remains the same, largely.

Thanks

Comment: How are you dealing with security?

Comment: I hadn't. Since it would be sitting within their data centre I figured the web service would only have firewall rules open to the relevant applications. However moving it off premsie would definitely mean mean more work in this area.

Comment: If the REST API is called from a browser and the page making the call is on a different domain then where the API is hosted, you need to look at cross domain access.

Comment: No it wont be on called via browser. All backend. Cross domain access would be a firewall issue surely? That would be done by the network team.

Answer (score 2):

You are on a right way to test your application on cloud in such scenario.

There are options available in market today where you do not need to change anything in your application and it remains unchanged while you will get all the advantages of cloud like availability, scalability and cost.

You can test your application on cloud using ravello where you really will not feel that provisioning and setting up an image as issue.

Disclosure: I work for ravello.